# Call log is not showing in my mobile?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, call-history

Call logs are not showing in my mobile from last 7 days. I did all things whatever I know, like clearing up in badge provider and then restart. I even removed the battery, re-inserted it, and re-started the device – but to no avail. It's showing messages whatever I am getting, but not calls.

What is the major issue, any s/w issue or normal only? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a software issue wherein the ROM you are using simply does not record your calls. Are you using a Samsung Original ROM or are you using a Rooted Custom ROM. If you would post more details about you Software by going into System Settings->About Phone and posting a screenshot of the same, I'll be happy to help.

You can also visit this website ([www.galaxys2root.com](http://www.galaxys2root.com)) in case you would like to switch your ROM in for a better one. I have a GT-i9100 and frequently use the same website to try different ROMs.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
Later I noticed that my phone's date was set to year 1970. I corrected date. And now the problem is solved.